# How to scan and detect only as single plane at a time in Unity ARkit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I was testing UnityARhitTestExample scene.The problem is when I try to detect a horizontal/vertical surface many planes are detected.It gives a awkward look when opening the app.Is there a way to limit scan to pick only a single plane or single surface.Can I convert all planes detected into one single plane?Which is really what I want.

When I asked in unity forum I got an answer but I dont have a clue what it said.Answer is the pic I attached.I tried printing the identifierStr while detecting planes but I could not display as text(null values I think).[image: Answer]

```
public  ARPlaneAnchor value;
void Update () 
    {
       Debug.Log("Identifier " + value.identifier);
       text1.text = value.identifier;

    }
```

Comment: He says keep track of all the detected planes in a Dictionary and do whatever you want with them. I have not used ARKit but it must be similar to ARCore it will keep detecting new planes or updating existing planes unless you disable plane detection. The solution to your question depends highly on what you want to do with the detected planes.

Comment: @AliKanat How to get each plane...How to save it?Any examples?